# Issues with creating circular progress bar

Tags: swift, drawrect

I have been trying to implement a circular progress bar in my app, however I have been having a few issues.

This is my code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var progress: CGFloat = 0.7
    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.5

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(budgetDisplayView.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
    var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, budgetDisplayView.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFill").CGImage)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

I am getting an error - Method does not override any method from its superclass.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to inherit from UIViewController, which has neither a `drawRect` method nor a `bounds` property. You should be inheriting from UIView instead.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be in a view controller, which doesn't have a `bounds` property. This code should be in a `UIView` subclass, as your `drawRect:` method isn't even going to be called.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The bounds issues is now resolved, but I've updated my question...

Comment: What did you change the superclass to?

Comment: I changed it to a UIView and that solved the issues. My last question is how I actually get the progress circle to be displayed in my view?

Comment: FYI please don't edit and totally change your question on SO.  Instead mark an answer as the right one and open a new question if you need more help.